# Is the integration of MS Power Apps Forms into Excel a viable practical alternative to using native VBA userforms within Excel

Tags: excel, vba, forms, userform, powerapps

I have been working on an experimental clinical data analysis tool in Excel using VBA userforms for the data entry UI. Because there are more than 100 unique userforms (and growing) it has become necessary to build the UI screens programmatically at runtime to avoid the VBA environment in Excel freezing when more than +/- 40 userforms are stored. I have been helped greatly at Stack Overflow to help programmatically build the userforms.

Recently I discovered Power Apps forms. It looks better than VBA userforms, has built in SQL functionality, but more importantly the forms will exist outside of Excel's finicky VBA environment. There is almost no online information out there about the integration of Power Apps in Excel. I need to remain using Excel spreadsheet to crunch the data because it is the comfortable and familiar sandbox for me to play in.

So my question, is integration of MS Power App Forms into Excel a viable alternative to replace native VBA userform functionality in Excel? I want to know ahead of time to avoid entering a time consuming rabbit hole just to discover it is not actually viable.

Comment: You could try using twinBasic to provide a dll holding your forms.  You'd then just need to instantiate the forms in the VBA environment.  https://twinbasic.com/preview.html

Comment: That also looks interesting. If I understand correctly, store the userforms remotely in dll form, then call them into Excel VBA one by one, or group by group when needed.

Comment: Forms are just a special case of a class with a predeclared instance. so you can do with them anything you can do with a class  To move stuff out of excel  you would store the definition of the forms in the dll created by twinbasic and then create an instance of the form from excel vba.  If you have defined frmpKaData  you would create an instance of the form using Dim mypKaData = new frmpKaData.  I would hope that you are in fact using your own instances of forms rather than the default instances.

Comment: If you haven't done so yet, please install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and pay attention to the code inspections.  You will learn a lot on how to write correct, robust VBA.

Comment: @freeflow, thanks for your input. Paradoxically it is useful as no one has replied about the the option to use Power Apps forms, and after looking into it more it is not worth it and will stick with VBA. Twinbasic looks stuck in prototype mode so I will continue with the 'UI API' of sorts I am making with userforms in Excel which will create all the variants of the uniformly. Rubberduck I think will be useful in tying it all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the best answer to my question is a non-answer. After several weeks no one has provided input as to how the integration of MS Power Apps forms into Excel can best can be achieved. It is likely not a feasible alternative to VBA userforms at this time (early 2023).